# bash: result of multiple echo commands with a delay on one line?

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm learning the basics on bash scripting, and basically what I'm trying to do is have an output of "..." with a pause in between each period.

I've tried `echo . ; sleep 1 ;echo . ; sleep 1 ; echo . ; sleep 1` and other ways but the output is always vertically, line by line.  I'm aware of what ";" and "&&" does but I'm just learning, and the only way that seemed close was a "echo . `sleep 1 command... 
Is echo or sleep even the right command for this?

Sorry for being so dim-witted but I just can't figure this out!

Comment: Yes you are going correct..hope you enjoy bash shell scripting

Comment: Yup, I'm shaking my head in disbelief. Thanks

Comment: Feel free to take a look at `help echo`.

Comment: Also you can use echo -n "..." to ignore the newline character and print on the same line. answer edited to demonstrate this. printf is also good too

Comment: @Cyrus - LOL I was trying echo -h / --help but all that was doing was echoing it back to me.  I ended up using man echo after.  I'm gonna love this bash scripting stuff smh..Thanks Xorg for your help! I'm busy "..."-ing away now!

Comment: @Mike Hunt: With bash builtin commands (see: `type echo` or only `help`) you can use `help <command>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your are looking to echo `...`

```
echo "..." ; sleep 1 ;echo "..." ; sleep 1 ; echo "..." ; sleep 1
```

echo as the name implies is to "output" and yes "sleep" is definitely the command you need to for pausing.

if you want to use echo and output `...` on  the same line three times. you can use

```
 echo -n "..." ; sleep 1 ;echo -n "..." ; sleep 1 ; echo -n "..." ; sleep 1
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I needed - pt.2 of the answer. Is it agaisnt the rules to ask for any good resources on bash?

Comment: No. not against the rules for me.There are lots of resources on bash scripting.However, I like the text "Linux Shell Scripting with Bash" by Ken O. Burtch  A really well detailed bash text book.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out.  I'm also enrolled in an online linux beginners course but right now we are just going through the history of unix/linux and the different OS's, so I wandered off and needed help.  I'm glad to have found a place that ain't so hard on the newbies! Thanks again!

Comment: Another excellent resource that all bash users ought to know about is GreyCat's [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) and the accompanying BashFAQ. BTW, although `echo` is fine here, beware of using it to print arbitrary data; `printf` is generally a better choice. Stéphane Chazelas (the guy who discovered the Shellshock bug) explains why [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/88378).

Answer (score 1):

`echo` automatically prints a newline after its arguments. To suppress it, you might be able to use the `-n` option, but that isn't universally supported. Instead, use `printf`.

```
printf '.'; sleep 1; printf '.'; sleep 1; printf '.'; sleep 1
```

Comment: Ah it was echo printing the newline...for some reason I thought it was my use of ';', thanks!